# on storage class whereabout

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a vector which takes a struct `point` as its type, see snippet below. A function adds two points into it. Since the points here are locally initialized. Is there an issue/concern that the points will not be accessible when the function returns? Is there a `copy` action happening inside the vector container, if so, where are these data struct actually stored? in heap?

```
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
    string name;
};

vector<point> pointvec;

int addpoints() {
    point p1 {2, 3, "point 1"};
    point p2 {4, 4, "point 2"};

    pointvec.push_back(p1);
    pointvec.push_back(p2);

}
```

Comment: Yes, the `point`s are either copied or moved into the vector's internal array. Therefore there should be no issues accessing them after the function returns.

Comment: hmm ... either "move" or "copy"? - to me, there seems be a difference as far as memory management is concerned. maybe it doesn't matter?

Comment: [Official documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back). And for the user of the vector (i.e.: you) it "doesn't matter", the `vector` handles its memory itself (which is one of the main reason it is preferable over using C style arrays).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector` starts with no memory allocated.  During the first `push_back`, it allocates enough room for that one element and copies the passed point in.  During the next `push_back`, it reallocates enough room for both elements, and moves its copy of the previous element to the new memory then copies the second point.  If you were to `push_back` again, it would allocate enough room for (typically) 4 elements, move its copies, and copy the new one.

There are standardized restrictions (amortized constancy) on the complexity of these operations which require the allocated vector memory to grow proportionally to the vectors current length.  The reason it must grow proportionally is because of the moves for existing elements (like the second `push_back` described above).  That means the complexity of a reallocation grows with the length of the vector, and amortized constant insertions would no longer be amortized constant.  To counteract that, the reallocation must be proportional to the length.  This proportionality is typically 2x the current length, though I don't believe it is required to be.

The memory in your example is allocated on the heap, but if you were to provide a different allocator type for the vector, it could be allocated anywhere an allocator allows.

So, your example is safe, but it is slow, and typically requires 2 allocations on the heap for that simple function.  A better solution is to preallocate the necessary memory using the `reserve` method which only allocates heap memory once.

```
int addpoints() {
    point p1 {2, 3, "point 1"};
    point p2 {4, 4, "point 2"};

    pointvec.reserve(2);

    pointvec.push_back(p1);
    pointvec.push_back(p2);
}
```

Comment: Minor niggle. There is no guarantee that data is stored on the heap. There is no guarantee that there is a heap.